# How to group elements in dataframe by row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-imaging-library, minecraft

I have [this code](https://github.com/Eric-Mendes/pixel-art-map) that essentially translates pixels of an image to a block in minecraft and it gives you a "map" of where to put that block in order to form the image in the game: the code generates a csv file where each cell in the spreadsheet corresponds to a block.

I want to improve this and not only output the csv file, but also output a txt file with the minecraft commands that'll generate the image in game.

Also, those commands have to have a relative position to the player's (x, y, z) which should be informed in the code via a tuple or something.

So, assuming that the player is at 0, 0, 0 in game, and my csv looks like
[image: csv example]

Here's this same dataframe in dict form for testing

```
{0: {0: 'minecraft:diorite', 1: 'minecraft:diorite', 2: 'minecraft:stone'},
 1: {0: 'minecraft:stone', 1: 'minecraft:stone', 2: 'minecraft:cobblestone'},
 2: {0: 'minecraft:block_of_raw_iron',
  1: 'minecraft:diamond_block',
  2: 'minecraft:gold_block'}}
```

I want my txt output to be

```
/fill 0 0 0 0 0 1 minecraft:diorite
/fill 0 0 2 0 0 2 minecraft:stone

/fill 1 0 0 1 0 1 minecraft:stone
/fill 1 0 2 1 0 2 minecraft:cobblestone

/fill 2 0 0 2 0 0 minecraft:block_of_raw_iron
/fill 2 0 1 2 0 1 minecraft:diamond_block
/fill 2 0 2 2 0 2 minecraft:gold_block
```

To those who don't know minecraft command syntax:

```
/fill {x_start} {y_start} {z_start} {x_end} {y_end} {z_end} {block}
```

with [start, end] (both included) and x going sideways and z going up or down.

I've tried nearly everything but I almost gave up on this code and so I deleted my progress, sorry :(

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1.: For even better testing, here's Naruto's pixel art (the first 5 rows)

```
{0: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 1: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 2: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 3: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 4: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 5: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 6: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 7: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 8: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 9: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 10: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 11: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 12: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 13: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 14: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:block_of_raw_iron'}, 15: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:sand'}, 16: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:snow_block'}, 17: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:snow_block'}, 18: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:snow_block'}, 19: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:sand', 4: 'minecraft:sand'}, 20: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:sand', 3: 'minecraft:block_of_gold', 4: 'minecraft:sponge'}, 21: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:snow_block', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:sand'}, 22: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:snow_block', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:snow_block'}, 23: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:snow_block', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 24: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:snow_block', 3: 'minecraft:sand', 4: 'minecraft:block_of_gold'}, 25: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:sand', 3: 'minecraft:sponge', 4: 'minecraft:sponge'}, 26: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:sand', 4: 'minecraft:white_terracotta'}, 27: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:snow_block'}, 28: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 29: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:snow_block', 4: 'minecraft:sand'}, 30: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:sand', 4: 'minecraft:sponge'}, 31: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 32: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:snow_block'}, 33: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 34: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 35: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 36: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 37: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 38: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 39: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 40: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 41: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 42: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 43: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 44: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}, 45: {0: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 1: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 2: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 3: 'minecraft:diorite_slab', 4: 'minecraft:diorite_slab'}}
```

And (what I think it is) the expected output for the first 3 columns (again, assuming player's position 0, 0, 0).

```
/fill 0 0 0 0 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 1 0 0 1 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab

/fill 2 0 0 2 0 26 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 2 0 27 2 0 29 minecraft:mushroom_stem
/fill 2 0 30 2 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe in copy-pastable form? You can use `df.head()` to get the first few rows, and `df.to_dict()` to convert it to a text format.

Comment: Done @NickODell

Comment: What's expected output from "Edit 1"? You gave a dictionary of a dictionary. Are these assumed to be x and y? As the dictionary is always sequential numbers, it looks like a good candidate for multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @hesham_EE that's the output of what Nick proposed:
`print(df.head().to_dict())`. I assume that using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html might give you that in dataframe format.
Since it's a real situation the result is much larger and I can't quite tell what it is right now. I'll make and edit when I find out.

Comment: @EricMendes I took a crack at this, and I get a different result from you for the Naruto dataframe. I'm not sure if what I have is correct, can you check? https://pastebin.com/xte8JWHf

Comment: @NickODell it had some weird behaviour like replacing blocks that were already set by previous commands, but it looks like it's working. Would you share the code so I could take a closer look?

Comment: Does this somehow have to produce a minimal-length script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using mostly `shift` and `groupby`:

```py
def script(df):
    z = (df != df.shift()).cumsum()
    zri = z.reset_index()
    ix_name = z.index.name
    co_name = z.columns.name
    for i in z:
        v = zri.groupby(i)[ix_name].agg(['first', 'last'])
        s = {co_name:i}
        e = {co_name:i}
        for _, r in v.iterrows():
            s[ix_name] = r['first']
            e[ix_name] = r['last']
            material = df.loc[r['first'], i]
            yield f'/fill {s["x"]} 0 {s["z"]} {e["x"]} 0 {e["z"]} {material}'
```

How to use:

```py
# df is the DataFrame of your dict

# label the axes
df = df.rename_axis(index='z', columns='x')

# select which axis to make major
a = list(script(df))
b = list(script(df.T))
res = min([a, b], key=len)
```

On your first sample data:

```py
>>> res
['/fill 0 0 0 0 0 1 minecraft:diorite',
 '/fill 0 0 2 0 0 2 minecraft:stone',
 '/fill 1 0 0 1 0 1 minecraft:stone',
 '/fill 1 0 2 1 0 2 minecraft:cobblestone',
 '/fill 2 0 0 2 0 0 minecraft:block_of_raw_iron',
 '/fill 2 0 1 2 0 1 minecraft:diamond_block',
 '/fill 2 0 2 2 0 2 minecraft:gold_block']
```

On the first 5 rows you provided for "Naruto's pixel art":

```py
>>> res
['/fill 0 0 0 45 0 0 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 0 0 1 45 0 1 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 0 0 2 19 0 2 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 20 0 2 20 0 2 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 21 0 2 24 0 2 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 25 0 2 25 0 2 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 26 0 2 45 0 2 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 0 0 3 15 0 3 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 16 0 3 18 0 3 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 19 0 3 19 0 3 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 20 0 3 20 0 3 minecraft:block_of_gold',
 '/fill 21 0 3 21 0 3 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 22 0 3 23 0 3 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 24 0 3 24 0 3 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 25 0 3 25 0 3 minecraft:sponge',
 '/fill 26 0 3 26 0 3 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 27 0 3 29 0 3 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 30 0 3 30 0 3 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 31 0 3 45 0 3 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 0 0 4 13 0 4 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 14 0 4 14 0 4 minecraft:block_of_raw_iron',
 '/fill 15 0 4 15 0 4 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 16 0 4 18 0 4 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 19 0 4 19 0 4 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 20 0 4 20 0 4 minecraft:sponge',
 '/fill 21 0 4 21 0 4 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 22 0 4 22 0 4 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 23 0 4 23 0 4 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 24 0 4 24 0 4 minecraft:block_of_gold',
 '/fill 25 0 4 25 0 4 minecraft:sponge',
 '/fill 26 0 4 26 0 4 minecraft:white_terracotta',
 '/fill 27 0 4 27 0 4 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 28 0 4 28 0 4 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 29 0 4 29 0 4 minecraft:sand',
 '/fill 30 0 4 30 0 4 minecraft:sponge',
 '/fill 31 0 4 31 0 4 minecraft:diorite_slab',
 '/fill 32 0 4 32 0 4 minecraft:snow_block',
 '/fill 33 0 4 45 0 4 minecraft:diorite_slab']
```

**Addendum**: make the script relative to a current position.

```py
import numpy as np


def script(df, at=(0,0,0)):
    z = (df != df.shift()).cumsum()
    zri = z.reset_index()
    ix_name = z.index.name
    co_name = z.columns.name
    for i in z:
        v = zri.groupby(i)[ix_name].agg(['first', 'last'])
        s = {co_name:i}
        e = {co_name:i}
        for _, r in v.iterrows():
            s[ix_name] = r['first']
            e[ix_name] = r['last']
            material = df.loc[r['first'], i]
            sp = np.array((s['x'], 0, s['z'])) + at
            ep = np.array((e['x'], 0, e['z'])) + at
            line = ' '.join(tuple(sp.astype(str)) + tuple(ep.astype(str)) + (material, ))
            yield f'/fill {line}'
```

Example:

```py
pos = (-5, 7, 3)
a = list(script(df, at=pos))
b = list(script(df.T, at=pos))
res = min([a, b], key=len)

>>> res
['/fill -5 7 3 -5 7 4 minecraft:diorite',
 '/fill -5 7 5 -5 7 5 minecraft:stone',
 '/fill -4 7 3 -4 7 4 minecraft:stone',
 '/fill -4 7 5 -4 7 5 minecraft:cobblestone',
 '/fill -3 7 3 -3 7 3 minecraft:block_of_raw_iron',
 '/fill -3 7 4 -3 7 4 minecraft:diamond_block',
 '/fill -3 7 5 -3 7 5 minecraft:gold_block']
```

Comment: your solution worked like a charm, however I still need this:

> Also, those commands have to have a relative position to the player's (x, y, z) which should be informed in the code via a tuple or something.

How would I do this using your solution?
Not always the player will be @ 0 0 0

Answer (score 1):

I tried writing a solution to this based on [un-pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the matrix of values into a coordinate representation, but the compression code ended up being hideously complicated, so I scrapped that, and wrote a solution based on a nested loop instead, which ended up being much easier to write.

Basically, this loops over rows, and within each row, it groups blocks of the same material, as long as those blocks are contiguous. (That's the purpose of itertools.groupby(), which is different from the Pandas groupby because the Pandas version *will* group non-contiguous values which are the same.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from collections import namedtuple

FillCommand = namedtuple('FillCommand', 'minx minz maxx maxz blocks material')

def compress_row(j, s):
    i = 0
    for material, group in itertools.groupby(s):
        num_elements = len(list(group))
        maxz = i + num_elements - 1
        yield FillCommand(
            minx=j,
            minz=i,
            maxx=j,
            maxz=maxz,
            blocks=num_elements,
            material=material,
        )
        i += num_elements

def compress_all(df):
    height = len(df.index)
    for j in range(height):
        yield from compress_row(j, df.iloc[j])

def fill_to_string(fill_commands):
    for cmd in fill_commands:
        yield f"/fill {cmd.minx} 0 {cmd.minz} {cmd.maxx} 0 {cmd.maxz} {cmd.material}"

def convert_pic_to_fill(df):
    return list(fill_to_string(compress_all(df)))

convert_pic_to_fill(df_naruto)
```

Here's the output of this code:

```
/fill 0 0 0 0 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 1 0 0 1 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 2 0 0 2 0 19 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 2 0 20 2 0 20 minecraft:sand
/fill 2 0 21 2 0 24 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 2 0 25 2 0 25 minecraft:sand
/fill 2 0 26 2 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 3 0 0 3 0 15 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 3 0 16 3 0 18 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 3 0 19 3 0 19 minecraft:sand
/fill 3 0 20 3 0 20 minecraft:block_of_gold
/fill 3 0 21 3 0 21 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 3 0 22 3 0 23 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 3 0 24 3 0 24 minecraft:sand
/fill 3 0 25 3 0 25 minecraft:sponge
/fill 3 0 26 3 0 26 minecraft:sand
/fill 3 0 27 3 0 29 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 3 0 30 3 0 30 minecraft:sand
/fill 3 0 31 3 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 4 0 0 4 0 13 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 4 0 14 4 0 14 minecraft:block_of_raw_iron
/fill 4 0 15 4 0 15 minecraft:sand
/fill 4 0 16 4 0 18 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 4 0 19 4 0 19 minecraft:sand
/fill 4 0 20 4 0 20 minecraft:sponge
/fill 4 0 21 4 0 21 minecraft:sand
/fill 4 0 22 4 0 22 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 4 0 23 4 0 23 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 4 0 24 4 0 24 minecraft:block_of_gold
/fill 4 0 25 4 0 25 minecraft:sponge
/fill 4 0 26 4 0 26 minecraft:white_terracotta
/fill 4 0 27 4 0 27 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 4 0 28 4 0 28 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 4 0 29 4 0 29 minecraft:sand
/fill 4 0 30 4 0 30 minecraft:sponge
/fill 4 0 31 4 0 31 minecraft:diorite_slab
/fill 4 0 32 4 0 32 minecraft:snow_block
/fill 4 0 33 4 0 45 minecraft:diorite_slab
```

Comment: your solution has worked just fine also, but I also need to be able to pass the player's position as a parameter, like i described in the question: > Also, those commands have to have a relative position to the player's (x, y, z) which should be informed in the code via a tuple or something.

The player won't always be at 0 0 0

Comment: Well, one could modify either compress_row or fill_to_string to take an offset and add it to the fill command. You've got the source code, and you can make that modification.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try!